# How to deploy a JAR file with all required JAR files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar

Can someone please explain how do i compile an app to a JAR file that will include several other libraries?

I have included three JAR files that need to compile with application.

[image]

I have tried to go with "Export/Runable JAR File Export" as suggested, but the "Launch Configuration" dropdown is blank.

[image]

I tried Running the program and it runs fine, also if I check the "Run Configurations" all seem fine.

[image]

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloade MAVEN plugin, converted the project to MAVEN project.
Then i included the POM.XML where i included all the dependencies and JAR signature.

The project is then exported as JAR file with MAVEN install command.